# How to take two arrays as output from Gym.Env to fit to DQN NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, openai-gym, dqn

Can't figure out how to make the gym.Env put out two separate arrays. It just seems to combine them into 1 array containing 2 arrays. But fitting to DQN NN expects two arrays.
I'm hoping to put the two arrays into the NN separately.

I've tried to show as much code as i can, but there's a lot.

I've tried playing around with the observation space a bit, tried box and Tuple,
can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong.

```
class GoEnv(gym.Env):

    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Tuple([spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(2, 11), dtype=np.float32),
                                               spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(1, 11), dtype=np.float32)])

    def step(self, action):
        state = [np.array(self.data), np.array(self.account)]
        return state, reward, self.done, info

envi = env.GoEnv()

def data_model():
    data_input = layers.Input(shape=(500, 2, 11))
    acc_input = layers.Input(shape=(500, 1, 11))

    dat_model = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, activation='swish', kernel_size=(500, 1),
                              padding='valid', strides=(500, 1))(data_input)
    dat_model = layers.Dense(3, activation='swish')(dat_model)
    dat_model = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(dat_model)
    dat_model = layers.Flatten()(dat_model)
    dat_model = keras.Model(inputs=data_input, outputs=dat_model)

    acc_model = layers.Dense(3, activation='swish')(acc_input)
    acc_model = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(acc_model)
    acc_model = layers.Flatten()(acc_model)
    acc_model = keras.Model(inputs=acc_input, outputs=acc_model)

    combined = layers.concatenate([dat_model.output, acc_model.output])

    z = layers.Flatten()(combined)
    z = layers.Dense(64, activation='swish')(z)
    z = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(z)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[dat_model.input, acc_model.input], outputs=z)

    return model

model = data_model()
model.summary()
actions = 3

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=500)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model,
                   memory=memory,
                   policy=policy,
                   nb_actions=actions,
                   nb_steps_warmup=600,
                   target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.fit(envi, nb_steps=6000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

> > > 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Worrall/PycharmProjects/Prject/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    dqn.fit(envi, nb_steps=6000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\core.py", line 168, in fit
    action = self.forward(observation)
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 224, in forward
    q_values = self.compute_q_values(state)
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 68, in compute_q_values
    q_values = self.compute_batch_q_values([state]).flatten()
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 63, in compute_batch_q_values
    q_values = self.model.predict_on_batch(batch)
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 1200, in predict_on_batch
    inputs, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 2328, in _standardize_user_data
    return self._standardize_tensors(
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 2356, in _standardize_tensors
    x = training_utils.standardize_input_data(
  File "C:\Users\Worrall\PycharmProjects\DocumentRecog\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 533, in standardize_input_data
    raise ValueError('Error when checking model ' + exception_prefix +
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['input_1', 'input_2'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
         array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])],
        [array([[...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a work around.
I hope this is helpful to anyone having a similar problem, as there doesn't seem to be a lot of info regarding the initial issue.

I input the data as a single array.

```
data_input = Input(shape=(500, 3, 11))
```

and then i am able to split the input in the model itself using tf.splt()

```
min1, min15, acc = tf.split(data_input, num_or_size_splits=3, axis=2)
```

and then run them through different networks before combining them after with concatenate

```
    z = concatenate([acc, combined])
    z = Flatten()(z)
    z = Dense(512, activation='swish'(z)
    z = Dense(512, activation='swish'(z)
    z = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(z)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=data_input, outputs=z)
    return model
```